# How to know if a video has been seen/hidden?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Using the YouTube Data API v3, is there a way to know if a video has been seen or hidden?

Reading through [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos), I didn't see anything on the `Video` resource that could match what I'm looking for.

[image: a sample image to describe what I'm looking for]

Comment: By “has been seen” do you mean that it is viewable publicly? And hidden means video is in private?

Comment: Nope, I mean that a user has seen or hidden a video. I added an image to the question to explain it more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Logically, “**Watched**” videos are just videos which have entries on your “**Watch** History” on Youtube.

You can get your “**Watched**” videos list through the API by getting your Watch History list from your channel. You can do that by using obtaining your Watch History ID which at the same time is also treated as `playlistId`.

Referring through the [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list), make a GET HTTP request to

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

This should return a JSON which should contain an object with “**watchHistory**” key. The value paired with it is your `playlistId` which you can now use to make a request using the [PlaylistItems API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId={YOUR_WATCHED_PLAYLIST_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

This should return a list of videos that your account has already watched.

As for getting the list of “**Hidden**” videos on your subscription feed. I think it's not achievable through the API. Checked on different responses of subscription and video resources but to no avail. No responses containing "watched" or "hidden" related.